# I'm getting this error after i upload my php file in fillezilla SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, html, mariadb, xampp

I'm connecting a php file to a database in phpmyadmin, when i try it locally with XAMPP everything works just fine and the database is getting the information.

It's a school project so i need to uploaded the code using fillzilla. When i do it i don't get any trouble and i check the uploaded site and when i submit the information i get this

> An error occurred while connecting to the database: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

I tried changing the name of the database i had it as database.sql and i remove the .sql , i change the the username and put it all lowercases. i remove the ad blocker from my browser .

Comment: _I'm connecting a php file to a database in phpmyadmin_ To be precise you are most likely connecting a PHP Script to a MySQL database !

Comment: Did you create a User account called `user` on the School server? Or were you told to use a different specific account to connect to MySQL.

Comment: PS: If you are using XAMPP, you are probably using `mariaDB` and not `MySQL`

Comment: Of course it might be that yo are using the wrong password

Comment: its because where you're uploading the file, on that server the credentials are different.

Answer (score 0):

@Alain Puron

- i am assuming you are trying to host your application on a shared hosting and service provider is providing `cpanle`
- in `cpanel` under `Database` you can see the user id and you can set the password there
- you have to use those id and passwords

hope this will help you or be precise with your question where you are hosting (the server you are uploading you project via filezilla)